# Rails RSpec controller test changes second attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a controller called "CrossLayerParamtersController". If one specified attribute (donor_layer) is updated. I want the attribute (donor_material) to be set to "0".

In the controller update method I'm checking if the donor_layer params are present and if they are the donor_material is set to 0:

Controller file:

```
cross_layer_parameter_controller.rb

 def update
    @stack = Stack.find(params[:stack_id])
    @cross_layer_parameter = CrossLayerParameter.find(params[:id])
    if params[:cross_layer_parameter][:donor_layer]
      @cross_layer_parameter.donor_material = 0
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cross_layer_parameter.update(cross_layer_parameter_params)
        new_rows = render_to_string('stacks/_cross_layer_parameters.html.erb', layout: false, locals: { stack: @stack} )
        id = @cross_layer_parameter.id
        format.html { redirect_to(@stack) }
        format.json { render json: { new_rows: new_rows, id: id, status: 200 } }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to edit_stack_path(@cross_layer_parameter) }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@cross_layer_parameter) }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is working as expected and I want to write an RSpec test in my controller tests that checks that. Until now I have:

RSpec test file:

```
cross_layer_parameter_controller_spec.rb

describe 'PUT #update' do
context "with params donor_layer or acceptor_layer" do
  before do
    post :update, params: { stack_id: @stack.id, donor_layer: 5, id: @cross_layer_parameter.id, cross_layer_parameter: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:cross_layer_parameter) }
    @cross_layer_parameter.reload
  end

  it "should changed the donor material '0'" do
    expect(@cross_layer_parameter.donor_material).to eq 0
  end
end
```

end

I suspect FactoryGirl is messing it up but I'm not sure. Is there another way to test wittout using FactoryGirl? I've tried the put underneath but this didn't work.

```
post :update, params: { stack_id: @stack.id, donor_layer: 5, id: @cross_layer_parameter.id }
```

FactoryGirl file:

```
cross_layer_parameter.rb

require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :cross_layer_parameter do
    donor_layer { Faker::Number.between(0, 10) }
    donor_material { Faker::Number.between(0, 10) }
    acceptor_layer { Faker::Number.between(0, 10) }
    acceptor_material { Faker::Number.between(0, 10) }
    interaction { Faker::Number.between(1, 9) }
    value { Faker::Number.decimal(2) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add params as params argument there. First part is type of action and action (put and update) and rest are params. Here is code sample for `put update`:

```
let(:params) { { attachment: '' } }
let(:action) { put :update, parent_id: parent.id, id: object.id, object: params }
```

Comment: Thank ti's what I need to only submit the donor_layer params. Unfortunatly the donor_material is not set to "0" as expected. I'll take another good look at it!